# Copy a file, creating directories as necessary in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a file at `/source.txt`, and I want to copy it to `/a/b/c.txt`. `/a` and `/a/b` may or may not exist.

Is there a way to copy the file and have it create the necessary parent directories if necessary?

Ideally this would be one command. In particular, I'd like to avoid parsing the file/directory parts of destination path and then manually calling `FileUtils.mkdir_p` and `FileUtils.cp`.

Pure Ruby is preferred, though a Rails-dependent solution is acceptable.

Comment: Why would you like to do that in one command? Most filesystems just work that way. You need a directory before you can put files in it. What's wrong with 2 or 3 calls?

Comment: 1 call is simpler than 2. If it *can't* be done in 1 call, then that's fine.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Typically it's up to you to make sure that the target directory path exists, so I doubt if any built-in command does what you're looking for.

But using [`FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p) could be very straightforward, especially by using [`File.dirname()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-dirname) to parse the path.  You could even wrap it in a utility routine, e.g.:

```
require 'fileutils'

def copy_with_path(src, dst)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dst))
  FileUtils.cp(src, dst)
end
```